# How to perform Numpy optimisation for this code?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

I have the following code snippet:

```
def func1(self, X, y):
    #X.shape = (455,13)
    #y.shape = (455)

    num_examples, num_features = np.shape(X)
    self.weights = np.random.uniform(-1 / (2 * num_examples), 1 / (2 * num_examples), num_features)

    while condition:
        new_weights = np.zeros(num_features)
        K = (np.dot(X, self.weights) - y)

        for j in range(num_features):
            summ = 0

            for i in range(num_examples):
                summ += K[i] * X[i][j]

            new_weights[j] = self.weights[j] - ((self.alpha / num_examples) * summ)

        self.weights = new_weights
```

This code works too slow. Is there any optimization, which I can do?

Comment: What is `condition`?

Comment: @unutbu, `count of iteration > 0`.

Comment: So is the `while-loop` infinite?

Comment: @unutbu, no. I just remove `counter` from example.

Comment: Do you really want to reset `summ=0` **inside** the `for j` loop? By doing so, you throw away all the work done by every iteration of the `for j` loop except the last iteration when `j` equals `num_features-1`.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you try to explain by what you are trying to achieve instead of what you are trying to optimize.

Comment: @unutbu, yeah, it is my fault. I fix my code. It is the real version of my algorithm.

Comment: @Alexander, it is just optimization algorithm, which optimize `self.weights`. It works correctly, but too slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can efficiently use `np.einsum()`. See a testing version below:

```
def func2(X, y):
    num_examples, num_features = np.shape(X)
    weights = np.random.uniform(-1./(2*num_examples), 1./(2*num_examples), num_features)

    K = (np.dot(X, weights) - y)

    return weights - alpha/num_examples*np.einsum('i,ij->j', K, X)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `new_weights` directly using `matrix-multiplication` with `np.dot` like so -

```
new_weights = self.weights- ((self.alpha / num_examples) * np.dot(K[None],X))
```

Comment: thanks for the help! It seems that your code works correctly, but a bit slower than `Saullo Castro`.

Comment: @Denis Yeah, that `einsum` seems to be the best one for optimizing solutions!